# Código para mostrar procedures no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Qual o código em MySQL para mostrar as *procedures* criadas por mim?

Comment: você quer saber como mostrar o código de sua procedure? vc quer uma lista de todas as suas procedures? seja mais específico

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que seja isso quer deseja:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_TYPE, ROUTINE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'nome do banco de dados aqui';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/ListProcedures.sql).

[Documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-stored-procs.html#faq-mysql-how-view-procedures-functions).

Também pode ser que queira  listar:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
```

[Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-status.html).

E mostrar o código:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE CODE;
```

[Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-procedure-code.html).

Comment: acho q ele quer o `sp_helptext <nome_da_proc>` mas não tenho certeza...

Comment: Desconheço a existência disso no MySQL.

Comment: voce tá certo. eu acho q ele quer um comando similar no MySQL